# Почему не выводится footer во fragment (Android)?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout, xamarin

Имеется фрагмент, в котором необходимо вывести header и footer, а между ними контент в ScrollView. Но вот footer не выводится. Специалисты помогите!

**Код разметки:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_dialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Fixed Header"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/window_background"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_dialog"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/color_drawable_button_dialog"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- Scrollable Item below header and above footer -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:background="#FA53427E">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Item 1"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы проставили у ScrollView высоту во весь экран. Вам надо

1. Сменить основной контейнер на LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией.
2. Проставить для ScrollView вес в 1 и высоту в 0dp

Тиким образом у вас каждый следующий элемент будет идти снизу от прудыдущего и ScrollView займёт всё место, незанятое header & footer

Comment: Сделал, как Вы посоветовали, но, увы, лейауты размещены в той последовательности, в которой идут в разметке. Когда меняю последовательность header, ScrollView, footer, то футера опять не видно.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решился удивительным образом. Разметку оставил прежнюю, т.е. реализованную через `RelativeLayout`, но мне нужно еще загружать картинку с инета. Добавил в `ScrollView` `ImageView`и в коде загружаю картинку во вторичном потоке, т.е. ассинхронно. И, о чудо, после загрузки картинки (доли секунды) выводится футер. Специально протестировал, загружал очень большую картинку, чтобы увидеть задержку вывода футера. А если картинку указывать в разметке, т.е.

```
android:src="@drawable/myPhoto"
```

то футер не выводиться!?

Чем обусловлено такое поведение?